# shop page with differnet image size in wp

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theme-astra

i have a wp website and I want all products, to have the same size of div.
now some of them are bigger(have more hight) than the others and some have been cropped.
what should I write in CSS to have all of them in the same size and all text below them be in the same line?

here is the website link:

https://www.montio.ir/shop/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should set image size in woocomerce setting.

1. Go to Appearance > Customize.
2. Then go to WooCommerce > Product Images.
3. Write your desired width in “Main image width” field.
4. Click on “Publish”

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).